# How to skip database part in constructor from unit test?

Tags: c#, sqlite, unit-testing

I want to perform a unit test for the function `calTax()`, and I don't want the database part in the constructor for it.

Since constructor is called automatically, I get this error:

> "SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Products_t'."

Is there any way to skip the database part in the constructor call from the unit test execution or to avoid this error?

Class Code:

```cs
//constructor
public OrderVM()
{
    using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        var list = db.Products_t.ToList();
        Products_o = new ObservableCollection<Product>(list);
    }             
}


//function I want to test
public void calTax()
{
    Tax = SubTotal * 5/ 100;
}
```

Unit Test Code:

```cs
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Calculate_Tax()
    {
        var order = new OrderVM();
        order.SubTotal = 100;
        order.calTax();
        order.Tax.Should().Be(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: simple solution: do not create a new databasecontext in the construction! use dependency injection to supply the databaseContext to the OrderVM. Even better, directly supply a list of products to the Order Vm

Comment: It's never a good idea to have a hard dependency on a database. You should hide it behind an interface and use dependency injection. It's also discouraged to use database calls, I/O operations or Tasks inside of constructors. Constructors should simply create an instance of a class. Any loading operations should come afterwards and should be explicit calls. Ideally, your class wouldn't know anything about databases at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use dependency injection or pass in the `list` directly. In any case, you need to remove the dependency on the `DatabaseContext`:

```cs
public OrderVM(List<Product> products)
{
    Products_o = new ObservableCollection<Product>(products);
}

public void calTax()
{
    Tax = SubTotal * 5/ 100;
}
```

Then you can test the `calTax()` method by passing a `List<Product>`, which might also be an empty list in certain scenarios:

```cs
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Calculate_Tax()
    {
        var order = new OrderVM(new List<Product>());
        order.SubTotal = 100;
        order.calTax();
        order.Tax.Should().Be(5);
    }
}
```

If you need more flexibility or you cannot pass an argument to the `OrderVM` constructor for some reason, you may want to familiarize yourself with Dependency Injection (DI) and Inversion of Control (IoC).

Comment: I want to obtain the "List<Product> products" from the database. Can you please tell me where should I put the DatabaseContext part.

Comment: Databases are usually periphery and should be hidden behind interfaces. Then you can use dependency injection and setup a DI container, which will then be filled in the entry point of your application, e.g. a Program.cs file or similar. Depending on your application, you may be able to use the built-in [dependency injection of .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection) or you can just use any other IoC container such as [SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.org/).